In Rick: A Mort Well Lived, does the name of the grocery have any significance?
The first scene of that episode shows various characters, all of whom (I think) are shards of Morty. Anyway, the grocer (who is part of Morty based on his voice) is yelling at them to behave.
The name of the store is "Chot's" and I am wondering if that is significant in any way. Is it the name of some regional chain (or a play on the name of such chain) that I am unaware of or does "Chot" have some meaning within R&M or does it refer to some other episode?
